# Brother MFC-8860DN is not working after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, printing, brother

I upgraded to ubuntu 11.10 from 11.04 and my brother MFC-8860DN (duplex and network printer, scanner and copier) stopped printing. I did not check scanner possibility. Now it is not important for me...

Before in 11.04 it was printing even without it's drivers.
I could install drivers from different brothers and it was working very perfectly with almost any driver. My brother is still working from Windows. Nothing wrong with my brother.

Now I even upgraded Firmware on printer, downloaded the latest drivers from Brother, found PPD file.

There is no result!!!

Sometimes it is not working at all, sometimes it prints blank paper and very often and very terrible it is printing rubbish in 1-2 strings and pull out paper many times until I switch off brother.
But it can print 20-30 sheets before I reach the button power off because it is networking and very fast MFC.

I myself a sysadmin and a programmer but I am not a linux driver developer.
If someone has a clue please advise.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the printer, and re-adding it?  What happens?

Comment: Of course, many times. The result is the same each time. It installs but when I print then please see above...

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me though I am in a VM environment with Ubuntu 11.10.

Use HP LaserJet 4050 or 4050n as the printer driver.

While in Printing
Add printer
Find Network Printer: enter URL for Brother MFC-8860DN under "Host". You can obtain the URL from the menu on the printer.
Select "Find"

Ubuntu will populate some printer choices under "Network Printer".
Select "Brother HP Laserjet 4050 (Brother-8860DN)"
Ubuntu will fill in "Location" with "BROTHER-8860DN"
and "Queue" with "BINARY_P1"
Select "Forward"
Ubuntu will search for printer drivers

Choose Driver
Select "Printer from database"
Choose "HP", "Forward"
Scroll down Models side of screen to "LaserJet 4050n" (for network printer)
Select "HP Laserjet 4050 Series Postscript [en] (recommended)"
Select "Forward"

"Installable Options" are next.
For my situation, I selected "Duplex Unit", Printer Disk: "Hard Disk", and Total Memory: "4-7 MB"
Select "Forward"

Describe Printer
Printer name:"Brother8860DN_HP-LaserJet-4050n"
Description (optional):"Brother8860DN_HP-LaserJet-4050n"
Location (optional): "BROTHER-8860DN_HP-LaserJet4050n"
Select "Apply"

"Would you like to print a test page?"
Select "Print test page"
"Test page submitted"
The light on your printer should be blinking....
with a test page not far behind.

MG Myers, MBA

Comment: Great.  Also works for MFC-8860-DN on Lucid 10.04.